# Typescript - get the function signature from a callback

Tags: typescript

I keep running into this situation: I'm handing off a callback as a parameter to a function or class that's in another file.  Unfortunately I can't import the callback's signature because it came from a parent and I'd end up with a circular reference.

**file Foo.ts**

```
import fn from "./fn"

class Foo {

    bar() {
        fn( this.baz.bind(this) )
    }

    baz() { }
}
```

**file fn.ts**

```
import Foo from "./Foo" // circular reference

export default function ( callback: typeof Foo.prototype.baz ) { }
```

**== Edit ==**
Idea from @youdateme's linked article: break it into smaller pieces:

**Foo.ts**

```
import fn from "./fn"
import abstractFn from "./abstractFn"

class Foo {

    bar() {
        fn( this.baz.bind(this) )
    }

    baz(...args: Parameters<typeof abstractFn>) {
        abstractFn(...args)
    }
}
```

**fn.ts**

```
// import Foo from "./Foo" // circular reference
import abstractFn from "./abstractFn"

export default function ( callback: typeof abstractFn ) { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're compiling to CommonJS which is why you can't use circular dependencies.

Of course, it's best to avoid them, which is why you can try [this article](https://medium.com/visual-development/how-to-fix-nasty-circular-dependency-issues-once-and-for-all-in-javascript-typescript-a04c987cf0de) to fix them .

ESM has built-in support for top-level await and circular dependencies, so I'd reckon switching over would solve it.

Change your compiler options to compile to `es6` modules or higher.

Then add `"type": "module"` to your package.json to specify that you are using ESM.

Recompile your TypeScript and run (ESM needs node >14 iirc).

Comment: thanks for the response and that article was interesting. I see where the author's coming from, but I'd want to ask him a few things, ex centralizing and manually building the import order sounds taxing, not to mention scaling sounds brutal. I'm stuck with CommonJS atm, that said I'd still like to avoid circular references. I know what a nightmare they can be in JS.  This felt different because I just need the signature and not the actual JS import. I was hoping TS would let me import the declaration file maybe. Looks like I'm out of luck though.

Comment: Actually the author gave the "break it into smaller pieces" idea as a what-not-to-do but I like that approach a lot. It's a little messy in my actual example because my method needs the instance props, but I think it's still a nice as an answer for the example I gave.